# How to get Button's onscreen coordinates

Tags: android, android-studio, button, coordinates, android-button

I am trying to get coordinates of button, so that using that i wanna set position of dialog box at that button when clicked. i have placed button inside a LinearLayout(Which is parent layout for buttons), so i used below code to get coordinates

```
x = b1.getX();
y = b1.getY();
```

But above code gives coordinates respective with that LinearLayout, I want coordinates of button where it is situated in Main Parent layout. I searched for it i dint get proper answers, please help, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use method `View.getLocationOnScreen(int[] location)` like so,

```
int locations[] = new int[2];

view.getLocationOnScreen(locations);
```

locations[0] will have x-coordinate and location[1] y-coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

Use `View.getLocationOnScreen()` and/or `getLocationInWindow()`.

You can only invoke it AFTER layout has happened. You are calling the method before the views are positioned on screen